# How to get row index of row containing a string

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am retrieving all rows in my datatbale using

```
var rows = $("#usersTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
```

There are 2 columns in my table 1st column : username 2nd column password. How can I find row index of the row which contains username "abc".

I tried this:

```
var rows = $("#usersTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
for (var j =0 ; rows[j] ; ++j ){
    var index = $('rows[j] td:eq(0):contains("abc")').index()
        }
console.log("index:" + index)
```

Comment: check updated answer is it working ?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change code inside loop. your are putting rows[j] inside a string which will not work.

```
var rows = $("#usersTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
for (var j =0 ; rows[j] ; ++j ){
    var index;
    if($(rows[j]).find('td:contains("abc")').size()) {
        index = j;
        break; //break the loop once you find your answer
    }
}
console.log("index:" + index);
```

Comment: Well this is not printing anything. I added console.log(rows.length) which gives me 173 on console. but the code does not reach 2nd console.log. And if comment the return statement I get the 2nd console.log but index as -1. I do have "abc" in my table.

Comment: can you make a fiddle? is that loop inside function ? check value of console.log(rows[j]) and post it here

Comment: Yes its inside a function and a for loop which contains lists of usernames whose row index is to be determined. `console.log(rows[j])` is giving me only 1 row. with `<td>abc</td><td>mypass</td>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110481/discussion-between-love2code-and-murli2308).